# htaccess URL rewrites with GET parameters

Tags: cms, htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite an URL to a CMS page and append some GET parameters.

My CMS page has the code "foobar" and can be accessed via "/foobar".
On the CMS page i have some custom logic which uses GET parameters, e.g. "/foobar?test=123". This domain can be called without problems.

Now i want to make that accessible via "/foobar_123" and tried it with the rule:

> RewriteRule ^foobar_([0-9]+)$ /foobar?test=$1 [L]

which isn't working (not found). I guess it's because of Magento looking for an CMS page called "foobar?test=123" ?

I also tried defining the rewrite in my config.xml, like that:

```
<rewrite>
    <foobar_test> 
        <from><![CDATA[#^/foobar_([0-9]+)#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[/foobar?test=$1]]></to>
    </foobar_test>           
</rewrite>
```

Which isn't working as well (leads to an 404).

How can i archieve the wanted behaviour?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a structure like `foobar/test/123` where `foobar` is your CMS page identifier. By default, Magento will try to match that whole string to a CMS page identifier and when it fails you will be presented with a 404 page. You can go around that by modifying `match` method found in `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` class.

First extract CMS page identifier:

```
$params = explode('/', $identifier);
$identifier = $params[0];
```

If the match is found we iterate over passed parameters and set them on request object

```
for ($i = 1, $l = sizeof($params); $i < $l; $i += 2) {
        $request->setParam($params[$i], isset($params[$i+1]) ? urldecode($params[$i+1]) : '');
    }
```

Putting it all together:

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }

    $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

    $condition = new Varien_Object(array(
        'identifier' => $identifier,
        'continue'   => true
    ));
    Mage::dispatchEvent('cms_controller_router_match_before', array(
        'router'    => $this,
        'condition' => $condition
    ));
    $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();

    if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl())
            ->sendResponse();
        $request->setDispatched(true);
        return true;
    }

    if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
        return false;
    }

    # extract page identifier
    $params = explode('/', $identifier);
    $identifier = $params[0];

    $page   = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
    $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    if (!$pageId) {
        return false;
    }

    # set params on request object
    for ($i = 1, $l = sizeof($params); $i < $l; $i += 2) {
        $request->setParam($params[$i], isset($params[$i+1]) ? urldecode($params[$i+1]) : '');
    }

    $request->setModuleName('cms')
        ->setControllerName('page')
        ->setActionName('view')
        ->setParam('page_id', $pageId);
    $request->setAlias(
        Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
        $identifier
    );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful! :)
Just for completeness, what i did was copying the file
"/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php" 
to
"/app/code/local/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php"
and made the changes there to be update-safe.